# Long parameter is not present error

Tags: jsp, spring-boot

I am getting an strange error i can not see why... because the id that it says it cannot find is in the URL: http://192.168.160.128:8080/deleteproposal/4 and i have similar requestMethod that work fine...

Exception: org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required Long parameter 'id' is not present
        Failed URL: http://192.168.160.128:8080/deleteproposal/4
        Exception message: Required Long parameter 'id' is not present

```
        org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.handleMissingValue(RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.java:251)

        org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:96)

        org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:99)

        org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:161)

        org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:128)

        org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)

        org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:832)

        org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:743)

        org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)

        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:961)

        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:895)

        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)

        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858)

        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)

        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)

        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)

        org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)

        org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)

        org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

        org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)

        org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)

        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)

        org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)

        org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)

        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)

        org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)

        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)

        org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122)

        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)

        org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)

        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)

        org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)

        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)

        org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48)

        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)

        org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205)

        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)

        org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)

        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)

        org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:96)

        org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)

        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)

        org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)

        org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)

        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)

        org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)

        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)

        org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)

        org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)

        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)

        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)

        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)

        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)

        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)

        org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)

        org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)

        org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)

        org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)

        org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)

        org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)

        org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87)

        org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)

        org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)

        org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)

        org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)

        org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)

        org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)

        org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)

        org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121)

        org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)

        org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)

        org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)

        org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)

        org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)

        org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)

        org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)

        org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)

        org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)

        org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)

        org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)

        org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)

        org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1502)

        org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1458)

        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)

        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)

        org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)

        java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The controller does not do anything yet....

```
@RequestMapping(value="/deleteproposal/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView deleteProposal(ModelAndView modelAndView, @RequestParam(value ="id") Long id) {

    System.out.println("!!!!: PROPOSAL CONTROLLER: DELETE id : ");

    return modelAndView;
}
```

The jsp is normal...

```
<c:forEach var="proposal" items="${allproposals}">
            <tr>
                <td>${proposal.id}</td>
                <td><span class="label label-warning">${proposal.proposalType}</span></td>
                <td class="hidden-sm">
                    <a href="${contextRoot}/viewonestatus/${proposal.statusUpdate.id}">${proposal.functionality}</a>
                </td>
                <td><fmt:formatDate pattern="EEEE',' d ' de ' MMMM ' de 'y" value="${proposal.release}" /></td>
                <td>
                    <a href="${contextRoot}/deleteproposal/${proposal.id}">
                        <button class="btn-u" type="button" >Borrar</button>
                    </a> 
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="${contextRoot}/assignonevotes/${proposal.id}">
                        <button class="btn-u" type="button">Modificar</button>
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
```

Comment: try @PathVariable(value="id") instead of @RequestParam(value ="id")

Comment: No, it says Access Denied. with no log error. I do not know what is going on

Comment: remove spring-security in pom.xml and try, if you don't use security for now.

Comment: Yes, it was a problem with the security. Thanks a lot. How should I close this question? It is not a good question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To match the method parameter name to the URI template variable (/deleteproposal/{id}) name, you use `@PathVariable(value="id")` instead of `@RequestParam(value ="id")`

Comment: but why can you please explain?

Comment: @Becauseihatemyself These are Spring Framework's style to obtain data from URL. You know, in REST, we want to get some dynamic data from URL to produce dynamic data. For example, If you want to response user specific data you would create /user/1 (uri template) or user?id=1 (query param). If you use Spring and want to get the id you can use "@Pathvariable" or "@RequestParam" respectively. You can also mix them for complex URL. It is up to you. Good work.